# How to set color of one row in NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

Who can help me? 
I want make the row to be red, but it is always all row to be red!

```
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell
  forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSColor *cRed = [NSColor redColor];
    NSTextFieldCell* cCell = (NSTextFieldCell*)cell;
    if ([[tableView selectedRowIndexes] containsIndex:4])
        {
            [cCell setTextColor:cRed];
        }
        else
        {
            [cCell setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of your selected rows in your table include the 5th row (i.e. index 4), this line in your code:

```
if ([[tableView selectedRowIndexes] containsIndex:4])
```

hits and you are seeing red in every row being displayed.

Perhaps if you change that line to:

```
if(row == 4)
```

(where row is a parameter passed into that method)

You'll just see one row changed to red.

To be honest, this isn't the best place to set a row/cell's color.  I think it would be better to set it in your table view data source (e.g. [`tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDataSource/tableView%3aobjectValueForTableColumn%3arow%3a)).

Comment: Half success
But I want the row to be red,not the setTextColor, is the setBackgroundColor
[cCell setBackgroundColor:cRed]; 
Why the row don't to be the red?